# DTS Headphone:X v1 - Please ... to use DTS audio controls

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I have recently noticed that for some reason DTS Headphone:X v1 keeps telling me "Please enable the PC Speaker to use DTS audio controls" or "Please connect a Headphone to use DTS audio controls", this as far as I know didnt occur before, I have had quite a history of issues with this driver/app not working properly, but this time I reinstalled all the drivers, even the Realtek drivers I had and reinstalled all of them from the manufacturers website and even though my speakers and headphones do work, DTS still keeps asking me the same thing. At this point I am not sure what to do, this is why Im here now.

Comment: It didn't occur before but you've had a history of issues? What issues have you had previously?

Comment: @music2myear previously I have had various issues, varying from DTS not working after a system update to even my realtek drivers crashing when DTS service started. All that has been solved, but no, this kind of issue, this is new.